# CriteriaQuery<?> ignore null value

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa, jpql

when i try to order data using CriteriaQuery ,it ignores all null values and special characters like '-' .
that's my code :

```
if ( "radical".equals((String) params.get("sort"))) {

                    if ("ASC".equals(params.get("order"))) {
                        query.orderBy(cb.asc(cb.upper(root.get(CONTRAT).get(RELATION_COMMERCIALE).get("identifiantRC"))));
                    }else if ("DESC".equals(params.get("order"))) {
                        query.orderBy(cb.desc(cb.upper(root.get(CONTRAT).get(RELATION_COMMERCIALE).get("identifiantRC"))));
                    }
                }
```

any suggestions ?

Comment: please post code as text, not as image and state clearly what you expect to happen vs. what actually happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not specific to JPA, Spring or their combination.

It is a basic feature of your database or SQL.
Something has to define what ordering actually mean.

AFAIK the details how to configure this is database specific and you didn't specify the database you are using so here is some information how this is controlled in Oracle. They call it [linguistic sorting](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B13789_01/server.101/b10749/ch5lings.htm).

In order to control it you have to either find a locale that matches your needs or [build a new one](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B13789_01/server.101/b10749/ch13cust.htm#1006767).
The key is the "Ignorable characters" which as you might have guessed get ignored for sorting. They include the "-".